# Unable to pass url parameter in JQuery

Tags: jquery, background-image

I am able to change background image using jQuery function without parameters, but not by passing in string parameter for url. What am I doing wrong?

```
$.fn.myFunction = function (splitId) {
    var finalurl= "/Games/Random/Resources/" + myurl;
    $('#shore-5').css("background-image", 'url(' + finalurl+ ')');
} 

$(function () {
    $(this).myFunction2($('ship.JPG)'));
});
```

Comment: whaat is `$('ship.JPG)')` supposed to do? just write `$(this).myFunction2('ship.JPG');`

Comment: my bad, I want ship.jpg to form a string and to pass it to jquery in order to change background image. But it fails to do it with parameters. Works fine without parameters hardcoded :/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eskensberg/wu012g6n/1/
This is what I am trying to achieve :P

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set http

```
$(this).myFunction2($('http://localhost/images/ship.JPG)'));
```

for instance

```
var myurl = 'http://localhost/images/ship.JPG';
$('#shore-5').css("background-image", 'url(' + myurl+ ')');
```

Edit :

```
$.fn.myFunction = function (splitId) {
        var finalurl= "http://localhost/Games/Random/Resources/" + splitId;
        console.log('called', finalurl);
        $('#shore-5').css("background-image", 'url(' + finalurl+ ')');
  } 

$(function () {
      $(this).myFunction('ship.JPG');
 }());
```

Comment: Thanks!, But it doesn't work. Also, the function works fine without the parameters - hardcoded, it's only if I try to pass the string over, then it fails :(

Comment: Edited and tested, make sure you have the id "shore-5" in your html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eskensberg/wu012g6n/1/
This is what I am trying to achieve :P

Comment: I've updated your fiddle, hope this will help you, click on the image to call the function